# unable to set or get a method from service throwing not a function issue in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

In my service:

```
 myApp.service('settingsService', [
       function() {
         var id;
          this.setObjectId = function (data)
          {
            id = data;
          }
          this.getObjectId = function ()
          {
             return id;
           }
}]);
```

From my directive: Note: Already injected that service.

settingsService.setObjectId(4); am setting like this

But am getting the following script error:

TypeError: undefined is not a function

If any one knows means please upadte. Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to work for me. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DOyiXyS1WiXnaKKFUKxw?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set up your service like this:

```
myApp.service('settingsService', function() {
    var id;
    var setObjectId = function(data) {
        id = data;
    }
    var getObjectId = function() {
        return id;
    }

    return {
        setObjectId: setObjectId,
        getObjectId: getObjectId
    };
});
```